# ES6 Add new elements to an array in state

Tags: reactjs

```
createNewList = (id, input) => {
   const foundCard = {...this.state.cards.find(card => id === card.id)};
   this.setState(foundCard.list = [...foundCard.list, input]);
  };
```

Hello everyone

There is an array of data (list), which is stored in the state for each object (card).

> Problem: I can’t seem to add a new element to this array.

The way it is set up creates only one element and change it every time. But I need to create a new one every time. I tried to create a separate array, add to it using `newArray.push (input)` and then do `this.setState` (foundCard.list = [... foundCard.list, ... newArray])`, but have the same result.

I don’t use Redux, because I just started to learn React and I store everything in state yet.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
createNewList = (id, input) => {
   const newCards = this.state.cards.map(card => {
     if (card.id === id) card.list = [...card.list, input];
     return card;
   });

   this.setState({
     cards: newCards
   });
};
```

Comment: Please do not make your answer consist of nothing but a snippet of code. Include some explanation over why the code works and how. Thanks.